# How do I make double partial horizontal line in a table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, cline

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ rcc|cc|cc }
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\sigma_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\sigma_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\sigma_3$}\\
\cline{2-7} 
\cline{2-7}
& $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$ & $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$ & $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$\\
\cline{2-7}
X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
N & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
\hline
\hline
D & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

In this code the two consecutive `\hline` are giving two horizontal lines in the table, but two `\cline` are not showing two partial horizontal lines, only one horizontal line is coming.

How do I get two partial horizontal lines in the table?

[image: This is how it is appearing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `hhline` package. The following image contains the two tables that result from the MWE as well as closeups of the intersections of teh double horizonta line with the vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ rcc|cc|cc }
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\sigma_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\sigma_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\sigma_3$}\\
\hhline{~======}
& $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$ & $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$ & $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$\\
\cline{2-7}
X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
N & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
\hhline{=======}
D & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ rcc|cc|cc }
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\sigma_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\sigma_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\sigma_3$}\\
\hhline{~==|==|==}
& $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$ & $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$ & $d_{s,w}$ & $d_{s,m}$\\
\cline{2-7}
X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
N & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
\hhline{===|==|==}
D & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)